# Utility to find Java class from where DB connection created and is still open?

Tags: java, jdbc

In the project say somewhere connection is not closed .

So is there is anything(any utility , api or something) in Java to check the Java Class where we have open DB connection ?

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: IMHO The best utility for this task: the programmer. The code opening a DB connection should also be responsible for closing it as appropriate...

You can find out who _did_ something easily. But to find out who _didn't_ do something in this case is a much worse task...

Answer (score 0):

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) can find such things: [Method may fail to close database resource](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE).

Another tool is [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/): [CloseResource](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.2/rules/java/design.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `netstat` command to see all open connections.  If you know host/port of your DB, you can check for open connections to it.

Comment: This will tell you that there is an open connection but doesn't tell you in which class it was opened.